# Application failed to start with classpath:

Tags: java-8, properties, configuration, runtime-error

I have an issue regarding the Application failed to start with classpath. And i'm using springboot version 1.5.10, and im trying to deploy as an independent jar on jboss. Im getting the below classNotFound

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySources
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.getFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:35)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
2019-03-26 17:35:33,919 DEBUG [o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener] [main] Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-32.jar,

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySources
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I can see spring-context is present in my maven dependencies, still i see the NoClassDefFoundError, as Above and please find Below is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>                    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
                <version>${consul-starter.version}</version>
             </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${cloud-consul.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
             </dependency>     
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox-version}</version>
                <scope>${dep.scope}</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox-version}</version>
                <scope>${dep.scope}</scope>
            </dependency>   

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- JAXB support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-remote-client</artifactId>                  
                <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
            <!--    <version>6.5.0.Final</version>  -->
                <scope>compile</scope>              
            </dependency>   

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
                </dependency>                   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
                <!-- <version>6.5.0.Final-redhat-17</version> -->
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-server-api</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
                <!-- <version>6.5.0.Final</version> -->
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <consul-starter.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</consul-starter.version>
            <cloud-consul.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</cloud-consul.version>
            <dep.scope>compile</dep.scope>
            <springfox-version>2.5.0</springfox-version>
            <!-- <version.org.kie>6.5.0.Final-redhat-16</version.org.kie> -->
            <version.org.kie>6.5.0.Final-redhat-17</version.org.kie>
         </properties>
```

can someone help me with the solution. Appreciated for the help.

Comment: are you trying to run Spring as standalone app? `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySources` it means you are missing the jar for the particular class. are you building it with maven/gradle? can share `pom.xml` if you are using maven or `build.gradle` for gradle?

Comment: The printed class path looks incomplete, cut in the middle. Besides that, everything listed so far should not be in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you have pointed out is "*ConfigurationPropertySources* Missing.

Cofig files must be always built again if any changes are made to it.

Simply head to folder where configuration file is located.

1. Press `Shift+Right_Click`
2. CMD will open , Write `gradle gAC`

Now build your project again, i.e DTO (*if there*)*and all other Java files, Now your program should run properly.

Comment: Configuration files are given in a config server, which is given the vault details, and will bring it from the vault while the runtime.